# PSQL connection to server socket fails when using URI but works with cli args instead

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker instance for postgresql. This is exposed to host on port `5432`. I also have a `bash` script that loads this uri as env var:

```
DB_ADDRESS="postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
```

Then runs a `psql` command like so:

```
psql ${DB_ADDRESS} -c "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1;"
```

The bash script is throwing

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

If I remove the db name from the env var: `DB_ADDRESS="postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432"` OR I run the `psql` command with arguments intead: `psql -U postgres -h localhost -d postgres -c "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1;"`. The command works.

**Why is this happening?**

Note: This is the `postgresql` instance in `docker-compose.yml`

```
postgresql:
    image: postgis/postgis:13.3.2
    restart: always
    shm_size: '2gb'
    volumes:
      - data-postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - .config/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
      - .config/pg_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    command: postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      POSTGRES_DB:
      POSTGRES_USER:
```

Comment: The yml file you show isn't setting DB_ADDRESS.  Where is that getting set?  That is where things seem to go awry.  Have you verified that the variable contains what you think it does?

Comment: This *Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?* is saying the connection is not being attempted on `localhost` but to the local socket. Where is the BASH script being run?

Comment: The bash script is being run on the host. In the same directory of the docker-compose.yml file (also same directory where the `.env` containing the `DB_ADDRESS` is located